# Microphone issue with Agora after receving a phone call

Tags: agora.io

We have a feature in our app which lets the creator of the channel pass mic to different users in a channel. When a mic is passed to a user, he becomes a broadcaster/publisher. However, if this user gets a phone call during the stream and after he/she keeps the call and returns back to the channel, other participants in the channel aren't able to hear anything.

We are listening to the phone state of the user and once he/she keeps the phone we are calling a function to resolve the previous state

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using the Web SDK? Is this on iOS or Android?